# Connecting to aurora serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am trying to connect to aurora serverless with:

```
psql --host=aurora.heremyauroroaaddress.com --port=5432 --username=postgres --password
Password:
```

and after i enter the password, i do not get any response from the shell. What could be the issue here?

After about two minutes, i get a timeout:
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "aurora.myauroraadress.com" (myip) and accepting

Comment: have you checked this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html#USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.Troubleshooting-timeout

Comment: Most likely you haven't opened the port in the security group.

Answer (score -2):

I just found the answer myself. AWS aurora serverless does not have a public endpoint. See also here:

https://labrlearning.medium.com/interacting-with-aws-aurora-serverless-1398c9de329a